# What happens when a ssl certificate used by port binding runs out of date

Tags: windows, ssl, port

When I run "netsh http show sslcert" I see one of the ports is assigned to a ssl certificate. What happens in the customer environment when this certificate runs reached the expiration date?

Comment: The clients should cease to trust it, and then take whatever action they are programmed to take.

Comment: Does Windows do anything when the certificate runs invalid? Maybe closing the port or something like this.